# Using JQuery on a window reference?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you use JQuery on a window reference? I have tried the following with no luck.

```
function GetDiPSWindow() {
    var DiPSURL = "/DiPS/index";
    var DiPSWindow = window.open("", "DiPS", "toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=520,height=875");
    if (DiPSWindow.location.href === "about:blank") {
        DiPSWindow.location = DiPSURL;
    }
    return DiPSWindow;
}

function AddRecipient(field, nameId) {
    // Get window
    var win = GetDiPSWindow();

    // Attempt 1
    $(win.document).ready(function () {
        var input = win.document.getElementById(field + "_Input");
        input.value = nameId;
    });

    // Attempt 2
    $(win).ready(function () {
        var input = win.document.getElementById(field + "_Input");
        input.value = nameId;
    });

    // Attempt 3
    $(win).load(function () {
        var input = win.document.getElementById(field + "_Input");
        input.value = nameId;
    });
}
```

Am I making a simple mistake?

**EDIT** For some reason, `win.document.readyState` is "complete". Not sure if that makes a difference.

I have also tried:

View contains:

```
<script>var CallbackFunction = function() {}; // Placeholder</script>
```

The method:

```
function AddRecipient(field, nameId) {
    var DiPSURL = "/DiPS/index";

    if (deliveryChannel === undefined) {
        deliveryChannel = 0;
    }

    var DiPSWindow = GetDiPSWindow();
    if (DiPSWindow.location.href === "about:blank") {
        DiPSWindow.location = DiPSURL;
        DiPSWindow.onload = function () { DiPSWindow.CallbackFunction = AddRecipient(field, nameId) }
    } else {
        var input = DiPSWindow.document.getElementById(field + "_Input");
        input.value = input.value + nameId;
        var event = new Event('change');
        input.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not completely. Internally jquery automagically grabs the local `document` rather than whatever you pass in for .ready. Other methods may work though. For full functionality i'd suggest having said window load it's own copy of jQuery.

Comment: @KevinB say it's not possible in an answer and I'll accept it lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is.... kinda. it depends on what you are doing.

You can use jquery on the parent page to interact with a page within an iframe, however, anything that requires working with the iframe's document object may not work properly because jQuery keeps a reference of the document it was included on and uses it in various places, including when using document ready handlers. So, you can't bind to the document ready handler of the iframe, however you can bind other event handlers, and you can listen for the iframe's load event to know when it is absolutely safe to interact with it's document.

It would be easier though to just include jquery within the iframe itself and use it instead. It should be cached anyway, so there's no real detriment to performance by doing so.